# Snowflake Data Loading issue great than STRING size 16777216

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

while migrating data from SQL Server nvarchar(max) to Snowflake  Varchar(16777216) I am getting the below issues, the error is throwing for only One record . Appreciate for any help on this.

```
" Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 62252375 File 'XXX.csv', line 24190978, character 62238390 Row 24190977, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"[notes:4] "
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard limit:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#data-types-for-text-strings

You may try to split the data into smaller columns while exporting the data from Ms SQL Server.